# R freezes when trying to install packages using install.packages

Tags: r

R freezes when trying to install packages using install.packages. This happens with all packages. No warning displayed:

`install.packages("TSA")`

Also tried:

```
download.file(destfile = "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Downloads\\TSA_1.3.zip", 
              url = "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/TSA_1.3.zip")
```

I got:
`trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/TSA_1.3.zip'`

Details:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2021                        
month          05                          
day            18                          
svn rev        80317                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
nickname       Camp Pontanezen
```

Using the browser, I can download the package install it directly using the link:

`install.packages("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Downloads\\TSA_1.3.zip",repos=NULL,type="win.binary")`

But I want to download it from IDE. Is it a windows firewall issue?

Comment: are you using R or Rstudio? I would suggest to reinstall the program

Comment: recently upgraded to the new version of r and rstudio

Comment: I've got the same issue. DId you find a solution ?